# Agregar las comunas de CABA a siniestros viales con pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Quiero agregar al df de siniestros viales con homicidios y lesiones un df de datos de comunas con la descripción de las ciudades que la integran, la población por comuna y cantidad por año. ¿Cómo hago?

Lo que hice fue lo siguiente, pero sale error:

```py
# Función para obtener los primeros 20 valores numéricos no nulos en una columna
def obtener_valores_numericos_no_nulos(columna):
    """
    Esta función toma una columna y devuelve una lista con los primeros 20 valores numéricos no nulos.
    """
    valores_numericos = []
    for valor in columna:
        if pd.notna(valor):
            try:
                # Intentar convertir el valor a número
                valor_numerico = pd.to_numeric(valor)
                valores_numericos.append(valor_numerico)
                
                # Si se han encontrado 20 valores numéricos, salir del bucle
                if len(valores_numericos) == 20:
                    break
            except ValueError:
                # Ignorar valores no numéricos
                pass
    return valores_numericos

# Obtener los primeros 20 valores numéricos no nulos en 'Comuna homicidios'
valores_homicidios = obtener_valores_numericos_no_nulos(siniestros_viales['Comuna homicidios'])
print(f'Valores numéricos no nulos en Comuna homicidios: {valores_homicidios}')

# Obtener los primeros 20 valores numéricos no nulos en 'Comuna lesiones'
valores_lesiones = obtener_valores_numericos_no_nulos(siniestros_viales['Comuna lesiones'])
print(f'Valores numéricos no nulos en Comuna lesiones: {valores_lesiones}')
```

```
Valores numéricos no nulos en Comuna homicidios: [8.0, 9.0, 1.0, 8.0, 1.0, 8.0, 11.0, 9.0, 1.0, 1.0, 15.0, 4.0, 8.0, 9.0, 1.0, 7.0, 1.0, 8.0, 12.0, 7.0]
Valores numéricos no nulos en Comuna lesiones: [14, 8, 8, 7, 3, 15, 11, 9, 1, 4, 7, 11, 4, 1, 9, 12, 9, 2, 1, 5]
```

```py
# Mostrar la cantidad de valores únicos en las columnas 'Comuna homicidios' y 'Comuna lesiones'
print("Valores únicos en Comuna homicidios:", siniestros_viales['Comuna homicidios'].unique())
print("Valores únicos en Comuna lesiones:", siniestros_viales['Comuna lesiones'].unique())
```

```
Valores únicos en Comuna homicidios: [ 8.  9.  1. 11. 15.  4.  7. 12.  3. 13. 14. 10.  6.  2.  5.  0. nan]
Valores únicos en Comuna lesiones: [nan 14 8 7 3 15 11 9 1 4 12 2 5 6 13 10 'No Especificada' 'SD']
```

```py
# Leo la hoja 'Cuadro 1.1' en un DataFrame
df_final = pd.read_excel(archivo, sheet_name='Cuadro 1.1')

# Visualizo
print(df_final.head())
```

```
   ID Comuna Código Comuna                    Ciudades que integran la comuna  \
0       2007      Comuna 1  Retiro, San Nicolás, Puerto Madero, San Telmo,...   
1       2014      Comuna 2                                           Recoleta   
2       2021      Comuna 3                           Balvanera, San Cristóbal   
3       2028      Comuna 4  La Boca, Barracas, Parque Patricios, Nueva Pom...   
4       2035      Comuna 5                                     Almagro, Boedo   

          Población Comuna año 2010   Total Población Comuna año 2010   \
0  Total población Comuna 1 año 2010                            205886   
1  Total población Comuna 2 año 2010                            157932   
2  Total población Comuna 3 año 2010                            187537   
3  Total población Comuna 4 año 2010                            218245   
4  Total población Comuna 5 año 2010                            179005   

           Población Comuna año 2022  Total Población Comuna año 2022  
0  Total población Comuna 1 año 2022                           223554  
1  Total población Comuna 2 año 2022                           161645  
2  Total población Comuna 3 año 2022                           196240  
3  Total población Comuna 4 año 2022                           229240  
4  Total población Comuna 5 año 2022                           194271
```

```py
print("Valores únicos en 'Comuna homicidios':", siniestros_viales['Comuna homicidios'].unique())
print("Valores únicos en 'Comuna lesiones':", siniestros_viales['Comuna lesiones'].unique())
print("Valores únicos en 'Código Comuna':", df_final['Código Comuna'].unique())
```

```
Valores únicos en 'Comuna homicidios': [ 8.  9.  1. 11. 15.  4.  7. 12.  3. 13. 14. 10.  6.  2.  5.  0. nan]
Valores únicos en 'Comuna lesiones': [nan 14 8 7 3 15 11 9 1 4 12 2 5 6 13 10 'No Especificada' 'SD']
Valores únicos en 'Código Comuna': ['Comuna 1' 'Comuna 2' 'Comuna 3' 'Comuna 4' 'Comuna 5' 'Comuna 6'
 'Comuna 7' 'Comuna 8' 'Comuna 9' 'Comuna 10' 'Comuna 11' 'Comuna 12'
 'Comuna 13' 'Comuna 14' 'Comuna 15']
```

Comment: ¡Olvidaste mencionar el error! Pulsá en [edit] y mencionalo en la pregunta. Por cierto, leé [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Las comunas estan integradas por barrios,  no ciudadses ;)